# How to fetch assoc in mysqli without foreach or while?

Tags: php, mysqli

In mysql, we use

```
$userdata = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * tablename where id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."));
```

And then we can use `$userdata` anywhere on that page....

How can we do it with `mysqli` without using foreach or while statement ?

What I have tried is

```
<?
include ("db.php");
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
 {
   $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

   $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable where id= '$userid'";

   $userdataraw = $database->get_results($query);

   $userdata = $userdataraw ->fetch_assoc();
 }
?>
```

Class Used as :

```
public function get_results( $query, $object = false )
    {
    self::$counter++;
    //Overwrite the $row var to null
    $row = null;

    $results = $this->link->query( $query );
    if( $this->link->error )
    {
        $this->log_db_errors( $this->link->error, $query );
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $row = array();
        while( $r = ( !$object ) ? $results->fetch_assoc() : $results->fetch_object() )
        {
            $row[] = $r;
        }
        return $row;   
    }
}
```

When I tried This, I got **error**

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_assoc()

I want set `$userdata` without `foreach` or `while`, is it possible in Mysqli??

Comment: `$userdataraw` is __array__. It doesn't have `fetch_assoc` method

Comment: The `get_results` function already returns an associative array if you don't set the second parameter to true. No need to call `fetch_assoc()` again.

Comment: @puelo Ok...so i can set as $userdata=$database->get_results($query); and can use it ? I am new to mysqli...

Comment: @DrManishJoshi Yes. If you only expect a single dataset and don't want to use a loop you would need to do something like this: `$userdata = $userdataraw[0]`;

Comment: @puelo Ohhh YES...It worked....Can you put it as answer so I can Mark it as accepted answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_results`function already returns an associative array if the second parameter is not set or false. Thus there is no need to call `fetch_assoc()` again.

Also if you only expect a single dataset and don't want to use a loop you would need to do something like this: `$userdata = $userdataraw[0]`to get the first and only dataset.